# twitter bootstrap css not loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have my index page head section as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge chrome=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css.map" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Until this morning, the page always used to load fine. But I noticed this morning that css isn't loading at all. I checked the locations of css files. It seems to be correct. Can anyone suggest whats wrong?

Comment: Well first of all, you don't need to load up every single thing you downlaod with Bootstrap. You don't need both bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css. You're also loading one theme, then loading another. All you really need is bootstrap.css, or bootstrap-theme.css if you want the alternate theme. The bootstrap.min.css file is a minified version of the bootstrap.css file, which is meant for production environments due to faster load times.

Comment: @MattD is correct. Go to the website and look at the example pages and the getting started page. Then download another copy, if you intend to host it locally, and correct your path names. Use something like assets/css/filename.css instead of using the version number in your path. It's now version 3.3.1.

Comment: The suggestion to use the CDN is likely the better option.

Comment: Thank you one and all. I have set a simpler path for css files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a problem with your browser calling the local bootstrap CSS file.

Try requesting the bootstrap CSS via CDN by using:

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

And then troubleshoot your local CSS file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It was a valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, try playing with the css file path. You may not need the "bootstrap-3.2.0-dist." Typically css is just css/bootstrap.min.css if it's located in a CSS folder and your index file is in your root directory.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that it is a browser problem. I saw that Google chrome gave me this issue but the website seems to work fine in IE and Firefox. I also have a more simpler path to the css folder now.